# If X,Y are random variables and Z = f(X,Y), is it possible for X conditionally independent of Y given Z

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say I have some random variables X,Y that are jointly distributed according to some probability distribution (not necessarily independent). Is it possible to construct a Z = f(X,Y) (i.e. Z is solely dependent on both X and Y with no other source of randomness) such that X is independent of Y given Z? I believe this holds for all Z : Z = g(Y) or Z = g(x) for some deterministic function g, although I struggle to prove this formally. One straight forward example is in the binary case with Z = not Y. However, is there any formulation on how the conditional independence requirement restricts the function f?

Answer (score 0):

If $Z = Y$, then the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $Z=z$ is, of course, the unit point mass at $z$.  A constant is independent of every random variable.

Comment: I appreciate the response, I wrote in the body of the question "I believe this holds for all Z : Z = g(Y) or Z = g(x) for some deterministic function g, although I struggle to prove this formally."